# Error : Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl,

Tags: angular, angular-abstract-control

I have made a weather API web application using android,

Link:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/maximlweatherapp

APP Url:- https://maximlweatherapp.stackblitz.io

I have used the same code in my Visual Studio Code and it is working fine without giving any errors but here in StackBlitz, it is giving errors
The only difference in both is that in my Visual Studio, Angular Version 8 is installed but here I am using Angular version 9,
Please can anybody see what is the problem with the code and suggest me some changes,

My Working Result from Visual studio Code output
[image: My Working Result from Visual studio Code output.]

Comment: That's because of AOT compilation. You should either cast `FormArray.at` result to `FormGroup` or use `$any`

Comment: can you please guide a little about it, how should I code that

Comment: @yurzui sir please look into this and if possible, can you provide me resources to learn all this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In AOT mode, which is default in Angular 9, template compiler is stricter than in JIT mode.

For example, in the following code:

```
[formGroup]="checkcity.at(itemindex)"
```

`checkcity.at` method returns `AbstractControl` and it doesn't match type that `FormGroupDirective` requires.

You can cast it by your own:

**html**

```
[formGroup]="getFormGroupAt(itemindex)"
```

**ts**

```
getFormGroupAt(i: number) {
  return this.checkcity.at(i) as FormGroup;
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/maximlweatherapp-1hv3r1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

or use built-in [$any()](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-any-type-cast-function) function in each place where you're using `checkcity.at(itemindex)`

```
$any(checkcity.at(itemindex))
```

Comment: thank you sir, I also read your blog on Medium regarding this and was able to get it right by using any, sure I will try with the above method also.